# npm problem when i try to install P5.JS manager package, EACCES: permission denied

Tags: npm, node-modules, p5.js

I'm trying to use npm to install p5-manager, and i run like "sudo npm install -g p5-manager", and here comes up with some mistakes as follows, i don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me?

---

npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
/Users/mac/.npm-global/bin/p5 -> /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/p5-manager/bin/p5-manager.js

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/p5-manager/node_modules/fsevents
>   node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error

gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/p5-manager/node_modules/fsevents/build'

gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /Users/mac/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/p5-manager/node_modules/fsevents

gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/p5-manager/node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

- p5-manager@0.4.3
  updated 1 package in 16.673s

Answer (score 0):

Try with `--unsafe-perm` in your case:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm p5-manager
```

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/454